# SQL Server: data integration how to integrate these two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two problems in the database.  One is the First name is abbreviation, the other is zip code is null.  I attach two queries. The first is the one I wish to modify.  The second is the desired table.  In the second one, the null zip is replaced with the closest year's zip, and the abbreviated FirstName is replace with his full Firstname. Note that the rows of the table are of the order of 10 million.  The number of row in the first and second table should be the same after the transform.  Thanks a lot.

----First query show the existing table content----------

```
DROP table t11;

CREATE table t11(id int, lastname varchar(20), FirstName varchar(10), Year1 int, Zip int, purchase varchar(10));

insert into t11 values
    (1, 'Smith', 'Rick', 1996, 32203, 'tv')

,   (1, 'Smith', 'R.', 1998, 32205, 'laptop')

,   (1, 'Smith', 'Rick', 2000, null, 'LCD')

,   (2, 'Derek', 'J.', 1996, 42201, 'Food')

,   (2, 'Derek', 'Jeter', 1991, NULL, 'Egg')

SELECT top 1000 * FROM t11
```

----Second query show the desired table content----------

```
DROP table t11;

CREATE table t11(id int, lastname varchar(20), FirstName varchar(10), Year1 int, Zip int, purchase varchar(10));

insert into t11 values

    (1, 'Smith', 'Rick', 1996, 32203, 'tv')

,   (1, 'Smith', 'Rick', 1998, 32205, 'laptop')

,   (1, 'Smith', 'Rick', 2000, 32205, 'LCD')

,   (2, 'Derek', 'Jeter', 1996, 42201, 'Food')

,   (2, 'Derek', 'Jeter', 1991, 42201, 'Egg')


SELECT top 1000  * FROM t11
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The following query expresses the logic that you want, using correlated subqueries:

```
select t.id, t.LastName, 
       (select top 1 t2.FirstName
        from tt1 t2
        where t2.id = t.id
        order by len(t2.FirstName) desc
       ) as FirstName,
       (select top 1 t2.ZipCode
        from tt1 t2
        where t2.id = t.id and
              t2.year <= t.year and
              t2.ZipCode is not null
        order by t2.year desc
       ) as ZipCode,
       purchase
from t11 t;
```

Your question is unclear as to whether you want to create a new table or update the existing ones.  The strategies for filling in the data depend on what you are doing.

EDIT:  (for closest zip code)

```
select t.id, t.LastName, 
       (select top 1 t2.FirstName
        from tt1 t2
        where t2.id = t.id
        order by len(FirstName) desc
       ) as FirstName,
       (select top 1 t2.ZipCode
        from tt1 t2
        where t2.id = t.id and
              t2.ZipCode is not null
        order by abs(t2.year - t.year)
       ) as ZipCode,
       purchase
from t11 t;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon.  You are excellent.  The firstname issue is resolved by your query.  The zip code do not.  I try to digest your idea.

Comment: @user1816353 . . . The zip is being replaced by the most recent zip before the current one.  Do you also want to look into the future?

Comment: I wish to replace the null zipcode with a not null zipcode whose year is the most close year as the year for the null zip.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you again. Good Night!